# How to insert image along with text in QR Code generator

Tags: php, codeigniter

Insert an image along with text in QR Code generator.So after scanning (text and image) both should appear on screen.

I am using `CIqrcode` library of php(codeigniter). For inserting text it is fine but for image that path is displaying on screen.

I have used `file_get_contents($path)` and storing it into `$params['data']` and passing `$params` as parameter

`$this->ciqrcode->generate($params,..,...,)`.

but only path is displaying on screen.

Any idea about this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below mentioned code for the same. Also make sure you have given enough permissions to your `/assets/qrcode/` folder.

```
$image = FCPATH . 'assets/qrcode/' . $id . '.png';
if (!file_exists($image)):
    $this->load->library('ciqrcode');
    $config['cacheable'] = true; //boolean, the default is true
    $config['quality'] = true; //boolean, the default is true
    $config['black'] = array(0, 89, 170); // array, default is array(255,255,255)
    $config['white'] = array(0, 89, 170); // array, default is array(0,0,0)
    $this->ciqrcode->initialize($config);

    $params['white'] = array(0, 89, 170); // array, default is array(255,255,255)
    $params['size'] = 100; //interger, the default is 1024
    $params['savename'] = $image;
    $params['data'] = '<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfPaO.jpg" />';
    $params['level'] = 'H';
    $this->ciqrcode->generate($params);
endif;
```

Comment: actually this is for text ..for text it is fine ..i want to insert one image for identification purpose inside QR code .ex- VCard .   in $params['data'] i want to insert image info ...text is working for me also..ok thanks.

Comment: You can convert image into binary and then add

Comment: in this way see $datapicture=base64_encode(file_get_contents($img_src));
  $params['data'] = $datapicture;  but not coming ...even $img_src is displaying path correct.

Comment: Can you please share your controller function code.?

Comment: i have shared my code as answer ..u can see above..similarly i want image info ..in $params['data'] = image... all text are coming fine and i have not done any extra config as u shown above ..for me its default config ...if it is possible then share me that code ..thanks..

Comment: IN your case you are adding image in QR Code right.?

Comment: yes ..i am adding image in that just like text..so for me only path is displaying ...

Comment: `$params['data'] = '<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfPaO.jpg" />';` You can use something like this, But you can not be able to put image in QR Code. You can store data or url in QR Code.

Comment: can we take <img /> tag like this in controller ?

Comment: Yes you can add inside controller.

Comment: i did but it is displaying full string of <img /> tag . not image again.    $getImg = file_get_contents($img_src);
$params['data'] = "<img src='".$getImg."' />";

Comment: i think it is not possible ..i am searching this since a week .

Comment: I mean you will get code for image tag with url, But if you want to see image instead of code than that is not possible. Because QR Code data will consider as a text not as a code.

Comment: is qrlib library same as ciqrcode library for codeigniter ?? cause 1 link is there for image obtaining after scan ..see http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/index.php?example=027

Comment: As I have seen this code, It might be help you but in this case you need to create `Business Card` for image.

Answer (score 1):

```
$filePath = null;
        if(LB_DESIGN) {
            $filePath = $this->filepath_model->getPathFolder_User($user_id);
        }else{
            $filePath = DE_PATH.'/web/test/file_system/user/'.$user_id;
        }
        $path = glob ($filePath."/photo.*");
        $img_src = null;
        if(count($path)){
             $file = basename($path[0]);
             $img_src = $filePath.'/'.$file;
         }else{
             $img_src = DE_PATH."/img/upload_logo.jpg";
         }
        $params['data'] = "Student Name: ".$row['certificate_name']."\nEmail ID: ".$emailId."\nAdmission No: ".$row['admission_no']."\nCourse Name: ".$row['course_name']."\nGrade: ".$grade."\nDate of Completion: ".$dateOfComplete."\nNOS/QPCode: ".$skill_code;
        $params['level'] = 'L';
        $params['size'] = 10;
        $data['myPath'] = $this->load->view('student_final_certificate');
        $params['savename'] = $data['myPath']."qrcode.png";
        $this->ciqrcode->generate($params);
    }
        return $data;   
  }//get html content
```